# Alias to method is being treated as a member function

Tags: python, oop, alias

I'm trying to alias a non-member function inside a class, but I believe Python treats it as a member function.

```
def bar(a, b):
    print(a, b)

class Foo:

    baz = bar

f = Foo()
f.baz(1, 2)

TypeError: bar() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

So I drop one argument and I get:

```
f.baz(1)

<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000026CD8279DD8> 1
```

Why is the instance being passed as the argument `a`?

If I were to alias another method, say from a module:

```
class Foo:

    baz = bar.bar
```

Where `bar.bar` is defined just the same but in the `bar` module, it works without issue.

Comment: There is *absolutely nothing* distinguishing the result of your `baz = bar` from an actual `def baz():` inside the class body.  If you don't want this function to be treated as a method of the class, try `baz = staticmethod(bar)` instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the claimed behavior for `baz = bar.bar`.

Comment: @chepner Really? Huh. Use a standard module like `open = os.open` then, the `Foo` instance is is not passed when called.

Comment: `os.open` doesn't define `__get__`; `bar` does.

Comment: `type(bar.bar)` is `function`; `type(os.open)` is `builtin_function_or_method`.

Comment: @chepner Why does `bar` then? How do I remove it?

Comment: That's essentially what `staticmethod` does; it gives you an object whose `__get__` method doesn't return an object that tries to pass any implicit arguments to the underlying function, but just those arguments that the `staticmethod` itself receives.

Comment: @chepner Understood. Looks like I need to brush up on the data model. This is one of those things I have just not encountered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `function`-valued class attributes are instance methods, whether the function is defined inside or outside the `class` statement.

Both `a.baz` and `a.bar` trigger the descriptor protocol, which returns the result of `bar.__get__(a, A)`, which is a callable that tries to call `bar` with two arguments.

If fact, you can trigger this method behavior explicitly without defining *any* class attributes.

```
def bar(a, b):
    print(f'"Object": {a}')
    print(f'Argument: {b}')

class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
bar.__get__(f, Foo)(2)
```

produces the output

```
Object: <__main__.Foo object at 0x108cb5e80>
Argument: 2
```

What you want is a static method, so that when you call it, the underlying function isn't given any implicit arguments, only those arguments passed to the method itself.

```
class Foo:
    baz = staticmethod(bar)

f = Foo()
f.baz(1, 2)  # bar gets arguments 1 and 2, not f, 1, and 2.
```

`staticmethod.__get__` just return the underlying function itself, not a `method` object that wraps the function.

---

Regarding the different behavior of `os.open`, you have to recognize that `os.open` doesn't have the same type as a value created by a `def` statement:

```
>>> import os
>>> def bar(): pass
...
>>> type(os.open)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(bar)
<class 'function'>
```

The `builtin_function_or_method` type doesn't implement `__get__`, so nothing "tricky" happens when you access such a value via attribute lookup.